# combine two files and overwrite original file using cat

Tags: bash, unix, cat

I try to combine two files using `cat` command, but facing a problem.

```
original.txt
============ 
foo
bar
foo
bar
```

following is my script.

```
cat original.txt | wc -l > linecount.txt | cat linecount.txt original.txt > original.txt
```

This script returns error that says "input file and output file is the same.".

Expected result is like this.

```
original.txt
============
4
foo
bar
foo
bar
```

Any idea?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can probably use:

```
{ wc -l < original.txt; cat original.txt; } > linecount.txt &&
mv linecount.txt original.txt
```

Or using `awk`:

```
awk 'NR==FNR{++n; next} FNR==1{print n} 1' original.txt{,} > linecount.txt &&
mv linecount.txt original.txt
```

Or:

```
awk -v n=$(wc -l < original.txt) 'NR==1{print n} 1' original.txt > linecount.txt &&
mv linecount.txt original.txt
```

Comment: The first one is nice and simple (though `wc -l original.txt` might be clearer)

Comment: `wc -l original.txt` also prints filename with line count

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`sponge`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/sponge) from the [`moreutils`](https://joeyh.name/code/moreutils/) package. I like it for that:

```
cat <(wc -l orig.txt) orig.txt | sponge orig.txt
```

---

If you don't have `sponge` or cannot install it, you can implement it with `awk` as a `bash` function:

```
function sponge() {
    awk -v o="${1}" '{b=NR>1?b""ORS""$0:$0}END{print b > o}'
}
```

Keep in mind that this will need to store the whole file in memory. Don't use it for very large files.

Comment: I don't have `sponge` on my OSX, let me see if I can get it.

Comment: neither my environment, anyway the function is helpful to foster my shell script knowledge. Thank you for help.

Comment: For `sponge` you need to `brew install moreutils`. What's the problem with the shell function?